# Syntax for dereferencing a pointer in C (or C++)

Tags: c++, c, syntax, pointers

I had a colleague check in code like this in C  (syntax #1):

```
(*(*(*p_member).p_member).p_member).member
```

When I asked him why he didn't use ->  (syntax #2):

```
p_member->p_member->p_member->member
```

he got really defensive stating that syntax #2 is more complicated than #1...I ended up changing his code because I had to modify it and couldn't read it, then he got mad that I actually touched it...

Which syntax does the SO community prefer?  Both are valid, but I find syntax #2 more readable.

I'm setting this to community wiki due to the question being subjective.

Comment: Are you confusing the precedence of * and . in your first snippet?

Comment: In #2, the last element, member, should also be accessed using ->

Comment: Frankly, I don't even consider this subjective. Given the choice of three operators (including the ()) and one, you can guess what I'd choose.

Comment: Yeah, I was contemplating whether to set it subjective or not - in the end, I decided to.

Comment: Greg, Trent, thanks for cleaning up my mess - I was typing in a mad fury between builds ;)

Comment: 2 is definitely the better way to go, you should show your colleague this question and the responses.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The technical term for syntax # 1 is "nuts."

That said, I'd worry a little about code that has to go indirect 3 times too.

Comment: heheh...
indirection was due to a domain model represented in C.

Comment: Think about using a temp pointer if you're needing to do this more than ones: thingie_s * tp; ... tp = p_member->p_member->p_member; then go indirect once through tp.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure, of course ... especially if your doing it more than once.

Answer (score 16):

I think your coworker is either inexperienced, some sort of neophobe, or just plain ol' clueless.  You're going to find that the unanimous choice is to use the -> syntax.

Answer (score 11):

In C++ I would definitely use ->, because -> can be overloaded.

In C I would use -> as well because it's much easier to read, faster to type and less error prone (hope your colleague doesn't get lost in parenthesis!).

Comment: I think overloading is a red herring here.  An iterator will work with p->a or (*p).a.  Use -> because it's far easier to read and far less error-prone.  Remember that *(p.a) and (*p).a are two different things, so you have to remember to use (*p).a, but p->a is nice and simple.

Comment: In theory operator*() and operator->() could be overloaded to do wildly different things... hopefully not, though.

Comment: which often overload operator*() as well.

Answer (score 8):

I'm typing off the cuff here, but my recollection is that the logic for the very existence of the `->` operator in C was explained in the 1st edition of K&R as (paraphrasing): because otherwise you'd have to type `(*p).a` due to the necessary precedence of the `*` and `.` operators.

To not use `->` for its intended purpose is nuts.

Answer (score 6):

I'll take door #2, Monty! Sure its more difficult to type, but its more clear than finding out which operators dereference which pointer.

Comment: FYI - Monty = Monty Hall of "Let's Make a Deal" fame

Answer (score 5):

You may also wish to discuss the notion of "code ownership" in your team. You colleague does not "own" the code, the company does. Hence anyone employed by the company, with good reason, can edit it.

Comment: The question here is not who legally owns the code, but who needs to maintain and debug a particular part of the codebase. If it is the coworker, I say the code should look the way he likes, even if most of us prefer the other way.

Comment: If anyone reading this wants the rest of the story - he started the code, I had to "integrate" it (add it to source control, put it in the proper process, have that process call his function)...it didn't work, so I had to finish it.

Comment: In my book, if it didn't work, he doesn't get to complain about you changing it. Of course, given that he prefers the (*p). construct over ->, I'm not shocked that it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

subjective huh ?

I'll take #2 as well!

Answer (score 1):

The second variant obviously looks clearer. The only reason to prefer #1 is the case of some weird operator * and operator -> overloading when #1 has really different effect than #2.

Comment: and if the operators have been overloaded such that they have "really different" effects, the author of that code needs to be dragged out back and shot.

Comment: overloading these operators will be banned in the coding standards of any project I work in.

Answer (score 1):

Bad colleague. Change colleague.

Answer (score 0):

I've had experiences where "->" wasn't properly implemented in a couple of compilers...  so the normal (*p).a  was more likely to work when you have multiple levels of nesting.

Answer (score -1):

No 2.

Having said that, don't offend people by changing their code, especially if it is a matter of style. It's just not worth it.

Comment: If I have to figure out what a single line of code says, rather than read it and keep moving, that's a quality problem.  I'd change it in a heartbeat.

Comment: So how are you able to work with other people who have different opinions what is readable and what not? I work with 40 other (and smart!) developers and pretty much everybody has their idea how the code should be formatted and what is readable. If we were stepping on each others like that, working together would be a hell and we would have never accomplished anything.

Comment: I would think coding standards would have to be agreed upon. Having a code base with a million different coding styles is a nightmare all its own.

Comment: +1. I'm with Nemanja: Sure it's ugly, and if you're taking over the code from this guy and making sweeping changes, by all means tidy this up, but otherwise don't bother. If you can't handle 3 levels of nested parens, *you* have a problem.

Comment: But 3 pointless levels of nested parens?  I would take offense.

Comment: I agree Nemanja - I would hate it if someone reworked my code, but I think this particular instance merited it, only because I had to eventually modify it.  If I didn't have to touch it, I wouldn't have modified it.